# Filter Pandas dataframe row and replace value in column

Tags: python, pandas, replace

I got a big list of phone numbers in all sorts of formats:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'phone': ['0123/12345', '0123-23456', '0123/4455-10', '0123-4455-22'],
     'name': ['A-1', 'B-1', 'C/3', 'D/7']})

  name phone
0 A-1  0123/12345
1 B-1  0123-23456
2 C/3  0123/4455-10
3 D/7  0123-4455-22
```

The formats I want are in rows #0 and #2.

When I concentrate on #1, I tried the following:

```
df.loc[(df.phone.str.count('-')==1) &
       (df.phone.str.count('/')==0)].apply(lambda x: x.str.replace('-', '/'))
```

And this does the trick on the number, but unfortunately also on the name column:

```
  name phone
1 B/1  0123/23456
```

But the name column must not be changed.

So I have two questions:

1. How can I filter the row and only change the phone column?
2. How can I go with #3, where I would want to replace the first occurrence of '-' to '/'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or if you're no fan of regex (like me), you can simply do this:

```
df['phone'] = df.phone.apply(lambda x: x.replace('-','/',1) if '/' not in x else x)
print(df)

  name         phone
0  A-1    0123/12345
1  B-1    0123/23456
2  C/3  0123/4455-10
3  D/7  0123/4455-22
```

Probably not the best or fastest way, still I feel more comfortable with it since I don't know regex yet.

Hope that was helpful.

Comment: Hi Rayhane, this would probably help me with #3, but it does change #2 that was OK before. And my problem is that I cannot filter and replace at the same time.

Comment: Hey cool, that does exactly what I need and - even more important - I do understand what is happening. Tx a lot.

Answer (score 8):

You can use *regex* replace (`str.replace` method) on column *phone* only:

```
df['phone'] = df.phone.str.replace("^(\d+)-(.*)$", r"\1/\2")
df
#  name        phone
#0  A-1   0123/12345
#1  B-1   0123/23456
#2  C/3 0123/4455-10
#3  D/7 0123/4455-22
```

---

Explanation on the *regex*:

`^(\d+)-(.*)$` matches a string that starts with digits and immediately followed by dash which is the case for row #0 and row #2; With back reference, it replaces the first dash with `/` and for row #1 and row #3, since they don't match the regex, no modification is applied.

Comment: It only works partially for me. While the matching part works, the replacing part deletes all digits in #1 and #3 and leaves a `/` only:
`#1 B-1      /
 #3 D/7      /`

Comment: I am using Anaconda with Python 3, latest edition. Unfortunately, I do not know much about Regex, so Rayhanes' solution works better for me. Tx for your help